# how to validate a field of object in Action using Struts 2 Validator

Tags: struts2, validation

for example, EditAction has the Object proposal, how to user Struts validation framework to validate the fields of proposal. Annotation or XML configuration?

```
<s:form action="/process/sample/Edit" >
  <s:select name="proposal.study" label="Study" list="#attr.studyTypeListKey" multiple="true" size="3" required="true" />
  <s:textfield name="proposal.familyNumber" label="Family Number" maxlength="20" required="true"/>
  <s:textfield name="proposal.individualNumber" label="Individual Number" maxlength="10" required="true"/>
  <s:textfield name="proposal.alpha" label="Alpha" maxlength="30" required="true"/>
  <s:submit value="Modify"/>
</s:form>
```

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/validation.html

Comment: are you asking about the differences between annotation validation and xml config validation and which to use?

Comment: it seems that neither of them can be used. As a annotation should added to a particular field and "field name" as well. proposal is the field in action, it has getter and setter, but I want to validate the fields of proposal like proposal.familyNumber.

Comment: I know the documents, but it tells nothing about my problem.

Comment: @nmc  could you help me?

Comment: @Jenny I really don't understand the problem.  Please edit your question and add more details to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code . It may be Work .

1. Please Check your xwork jar version and Struts-core jar . It should be same .
2. Field name and Textbox name should be same .

Comment: <s:form action="customer.action" method="post" validate="true"> may be its work